# Is Pentax still the only company offering an Astrotracer-like feature?

Tags: pentax

Pentax cameras have, rather early on, offered a mode that makes use of GPS data and the moveable sensor to compensate for star trailing, which makes longer exposures of starry skies possible. Pentax marketed this as the "Astrotracer" mode.

By now (2022), many other manufacturers also have the necessary hardware (in-camera 3 axis moveable sensor, GPS dongles) available. Is there any other manufacturer that offers a similar feature for star tracking?